# Pass by reference and objc_unretainedPointer from iOS5

Tags: ios, ios5, automatic-ref-counting

I'm attempting to use the SFHF keychain classes ([from here](https://github.com/ldandersen/scifihifi-iphone/tree/master/security)) with an IOS 5 project.  I've successfully converted most of the class over to abide by the new ARC rules.

I'm having some trouble with one small section of the code as follows

```
OSStatus status = SecItemCopyMatching((CFDictionaryRef) objc_unretainedPointer(attributeQuery), (CFTypeRef *) objc_unretainedPointer(&attributeResult)
```

This gives the following syntax issue:

```
warning: Semantic Issue: Incompatible pointer types passing 'NSDictionary *__strong *' to parameter of type 'id'
```

I'm rather new to iOS development and this has me pretty much stumped right now.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Note that the iOS 5 beta is still under NDA, so if you are in the Apple Developer Program you are violating your agreement by discussing this.

Comment: Thanks.  I've seen quite a few mentions of ARC not being part of the NDA here on SO.  EDIT** Link here - http://lists.cs.uiuc.edu/pipermail/cfe-dev/2011-June/015588.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the declaration of the API:

```
OSStatus SecItemCopyMatching (
   CFDictionaryRef query,
   CFTypeRef *result
);
```

The `result` is a pass-by-reference return value.

Declare a local variable of type `CFTypeRef`, call the function and pass the address of said local as per the API, then do any ARC specific shenanigans after the function call.

---

Yes -- the error is correct.  You aren't passing a CFTypeRef, you are passing a CFTypeRef* and objc_unretainedPointer() has no clue what to do with that.

Do something like:

```
CFTypeRef localResult
SecItemCopyMatching(query, &localResult);
if (... no error ...) {
   result = objc_retainedObject(localResult);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond, however, I have to say I'm still rather confused by the whole thing.  Here is an image from Xcode showing exactly which part is setting off the syntax error - http://i.imgur.com/XWE4l.png

It seems to be highlighting the "&attributeResult".

Answer (score 0):

Had trouble with this call, this is the code I got to work:

```
NSMutableDictionary *queryDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];


// Set some properties.

[queryDictionary setObject:[key dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrGeneric];
[queryDictionary setObject:(id) kCFBooleanTrue forKey:(__bridge id)kSecReturnAttributes];
[queryDictionary setObject:(__bridge id) kSecMatchLimitOne forKey:(__bridge id)kSecMatchLimit];
[queryDictionary setObject:(id) kCFBooleanTrue forKey:(__bridge id)kSecReturnData];
[queryDictionary setObject:(__bridge id) kSecClassGenericPassword forKey:(__bridge id)kSecClass];

CFTypeRef attributes;
OSStatus keychainError = SecItemCopyMatching((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)(queryDictionary), &attributes);

if (keychainError == errSecSuccess)
{
    NSDictionary *returnedDictionary = (__bridge_transfer NSDictionary *)attributes;
    NSData *rawData = [returnedDictionary objectForKey:(__bridge id)kSecValueData];
    return [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[rawData bytes] length:[rawData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}
```